# Managed C++: Dictionary with function pointers

Tags: dictionary, function-pointers, typedef, managed-c++

I would like to construct a managed c++ class that has a dictionary with function pointers in it so I can call functions based on what a string's value is. This is what I have so far:

```
public ref class foo{
public:
    typedef void *_Function(void);
    System::Collections::Generic::Dictionary<System::String^, _Function> _Dict; //Error: "foo::function" is not a valid generic argument
};
```

Comment: managed-c++ is not c++. FTFY.

Answer (score 0):

Use a dictionary of delegates, then have each delegate wrap a function that has the un-managed C++ code.